# Installation of MacVim to use gvim

Tags: macos, bash, vim

Previously I had gVim running and working; however, my hard drive crashed so everythin'g got erased. Anyways, I am trying to run gVim to open files "-bash: gVim: command not found. I installed X11 and MacVim and did everything that i did before but it just wont open my file. When i open my file with vim it works, but i would prefer gVim.

Any suggestions on how to get givm to work??

Comment: Isn't the MacVim command called `mvim`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012203/gvim-or-macvim-in-mac-os-x

Comment: ive seen that link before i made this question. did the same exact process and still doesnt work

Answer (score 3):

I’m a hard-core `gvim` user (i.e., I prefer `gvim` to `vi`, `vim`, `mvim`, and other text editors that are available on Mac). I’ve searched online for “How to install gvim on Mac?”, and have found many answers. The one answer that works best for me is as follows. Assuming you have `brew` available, on a terminal, type:

```
brew install macvim
```

You may be asked to fix some errors. Just follow the onscreen instructions, which may include running commands: `brew unlink vim`, `brew unlink macvim`, etc.

Once your `macvim` has been installed, type the following command:

```
brew link macvim
```

If this is successful, then `gvim` should have been installed, and you can verify this by typing:

```
which gvim
```

You should see:

```
/usr/local/bin/gvim
```

as the screen output.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you know what you are doing.

MacVim has *nothing* to do with X11 at all so… are you trying to run GVim — the GTK front end of Vim — under X11 (to mimic a Linux desktop, maybe) or do you simply want to run *some* GUI Vim (GVim or MacVim, whatever).

If you *really* want GVim, you can install it (and its dependencies) [from source](http://www.vim.org/mercurial.php) but, judging by your question I don't think you should take that path.

If you only want a GUI Vim, the MacVim download comes with a `mvim` script that you can put anywhere in your `$PATH`. `$ mvim filename` will work just like `$ gvim filename` on Linux.

You can even rename that script to `gvim` if you *absolutely* need a `gvim` command.

Comment: mvim doesnt work either. says the same thing as the gvim command.

Comment: @lonkey11 Do you know about the `$PATH` environment variable?

Comment: @lonkey11, can you explain exactly what you do *and* what your goal is?

Answer (score 1):

You can install MacVim either from this site:

- https://code.google.com/p/macvim/
- or for example from the `macports` project, with `port install MacVim` (you must install first `macports` (see www.macports.org)

with macvim you will get the `mvim` terminal command, what is an small *shell script*.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: gvim is aliased from the MacVim application's bin folder and you can add that bin directory to your $PATH variable to enable access to gvim from the terminal.

I recently downloaded the latest MacVim.dmg file from https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/releases, opened it, in the window that pops up, dragged the MacVim icon to the Applications icon, then closed that window and ejected the MacVim.dmg installer from the finder.

From a finder window I navigated to the `/Applications` folder, I right-clicked on MacVim.app and selected "Show Package Contents".  Then I opened `Contents/bin` and there found a set of symlinks from mvim and gvim to vim.

I opened a terminal, and changed directory to the home directory by typing `cd ~` . From the home directory, I typed `ls -al` to list all files even the hidden ones which start with a dot, and verify there was a .bash_profile file. (If you don't have this file, see if you have any other other profile files, or search the web to determine which to use or add, so that you can set the following additions to your $PATH variable and have them persist after you log out and back in.)

From the home directory, I used my favorite editor to edit the `.bash_profile` file, and added the following line to add MacVim's bin file to the $PATH variable:
`export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/bin`

I saved and exited the .bash_profile file, then loaded my change with `source .bash_profile`.  Now when I type in the terminal `which gvim` it lists that location, and I can run gvim from the terminal to open a file.