# Prepare vim environment to work with clang-format

Tags: c++, macos, vim, clang, clang-format

**Problem**:

> E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version

**Problem**

When I run vim environment and try reformat code (CTRL+K) i get this warning on the screen 
**Environment:**

 System: Mac OS X

**Settings:**

 Vim:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Nov 17 2016 20:17:27)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-91
```

python:

```
python --version: Python 3.5.2
```

**What I do**

- Update vim: 7.3 -> 8.0
- Update python: ~2.7 -> ~3.5
- I updated the .vimrc file 
  **from** 
  `map <C-K> :pyf .../clang-format.py<cr>
  imap <C-K> <c-o>:pyf .../clang-format.py<cr>`

   **to**
  `map <C-K> ggVG :py3f .../clang-format.py<cr>
  imap <C-K> <c-o>:py3f .../clang-format.py<cr>`
- Also I update clang-format file 
  https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/tools/clang-format/clang-format.py

Thx,

Comment: 1. `clang-format.py` doesn't do "refactoring". 2. Did you build Vim? How? 3. Show us the complete output of `$ vim --version`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solution:

 
1. Go to .vimrc file and add commands

```
map <C-K> :pyf <path-to-this-file>/clang-format.py<cr>
imap <C-K><c-o>:pyf <path-to-this-file>/clang-format.py<cr>
```

2.Add this https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/tools/clang-format/clang-format.py source code to clang-format.py file, you can save this file to i.e

```
<path-to-this-file>/clang-format.py
```

where path-to-this-file is path to direction where you put this file.

3.Save clang-format.py file and run vim. Check that the command works.

You can also install macvim for OSX. Instruction you can find here. [How can I install MacVim on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012203/how-can-i-install-macvim-on-os-x)

**PS:** If you get "Sorry, the command is not available in this version" error, try:

```
map <C-K> :py3f <path-to-this-file>/clang-format.py<cr>
imap <C-K><c-o>:py3f <path-to-this-file>/clang-format.py<cr>
```

Comment: `E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version` on macvim also

Comment: You don't have permission to access /svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/tools/clang-format/clang-format.py on this server.

Comment: `clang-format.py` is generally installed with clang installation. You can use:

`find /usr/ -type f -iname 'clang-format.py'`

to find the file and use that instead

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
$ which clang-format
```

returns

```
/usr/local/bin/clang-format
```

Then

```
ls -ls /usr/local/bin/clang-format
```

points to

```
/usr/local/Cellar/clang-format/2018-04-24/share/clang/clang-format.py
```

So I do

```
$ vim ~/.vimrc

map <C-K> :pyf /usr/local/Cellar/clang-format/2018-04-24/share/clang/clang-format.py<cr>
imap <C-K> <c-o>:pyf /usr/local/Cellar/clang-format/2018-04-24/share/clang/clang-format.py<cr>
```

This works on vim (from terminal) but not on macvim.

Answer (score 1):

Just mention the project https://github.com/rhysd/vim-clang-format

Which is very handy to use, and save us from repeated work.