# Vim -- how to let Vim support conceal on macOS?

Tags: vim, plugins, vundle

I install `Yggdroot/indentLine` plugin in Vundle. And input :IndentLinesToggle in normal mode, but no use.

Then I input `:version`, and find `-conceal`, so this happens.

`Yggdroot/indentLine` plugin must be useful in `+conceal` in :`version`.

Comment: compile with those options. try this: https://gist.github.com/dcosson/3686437 (not tested)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012203/how-can-i-install-macvim-on-os-x

Comment: Install NeoVim or MacVim, both of them have it compiled in by default. MacVim in particular is a drop-in replacement for standard vim, you can `brew install macvim --with-override-system-vim`.

Answer (score 2):

You could install Vim with Homebrew

```
brew install vim && brew link vim --force
```

Homebrew's Vim comes with `+conceal`.

Check this with `vim --version | grep conceal` — `+conceal` means you have it build with your binary, `-conceal` means that feature is not included in the binary.

To pick and choose what features you want in your Vim binary, you could always build from source. This allows you configure Vim to your liking